Same file stored on Azure File Share shows different last mod date on mounted disk (SMB) and in Azure Storage Explorer (REST)
I connect to the same share via mounted disk and storage explorer app (and also python api).
It could be important: files on the share were copied there from other drive using windows explorer.
I checked few times, but still I can see in File Explorer last mod date of a file set to 2012 (file is really so old, it is exactly so on the original drive too). But when I check the same file in Azure Storage Explorer, the last mod date there is 2024.
There is no other date metadata visible in Storage Explorer.
Any clue where is the 2012 date stored and why different dates are shown using different connection method - SMB vs REST?

2012 date stored data actually stored. I have a file create on 3/23/2022, and upload on 11/25/2024
$saCtx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "wbxxxsa" -StorageAccountKey "xxxxxx"

$file = Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName "wbxxxfileshare" -Context $saCtx

$file | Select-Object @{ n = 'fileName'; e = {$_.ListFileProperties.Name}}, @{ n = 'CreatedOn'; e = {$_.ListFileProperties.Properties.CreatedOn}}, @{ n = 'LastWrittenOn'; e = {$_.ListFileProperties.Properties.LastWrittenOn}}

## save to a file to check more
$file | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 > 1.json




Thanks wenbo, it does explain things. Apparatenly SMB takes the LastWrittenOn, and API  takes last mod.
